# Doesn't exit the 'while' loop

Tags: c, function, while-loop

I started learning c by myself,and today I learned how to use and create functions.
I made a calculator to practice on what I've learned,so I know maybe it isn't the most efficient way to build one.
The problem is that the script doesn't exit the while loop even that the value of the variable changed.
I will be glad if you guys can take a look and explain the problem to me.thanks!

```
//The function for answer

char answer() {
    char anss=0;
    printf("Do you want to continue?\n");
    scanf(" %c",&anss);
    return anss;
}

//the while loop
char ans='y';
while (ans=='y') {
.
.
.
char ans=answer();
}
```

I even tried to print the value of 'ans' right after using the function and I saw it changed,but it still doesn't getting out of the while loop.

Comment: Note that you have two separate `ans` variables in different scopes.

Comment: This is an example for something you would have been flagged by your compiler if you activated warning flags. Add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and make sure to read through all the warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
char ans=answer();
```

You're creating a new variable called `ans` inside of the `while` loop.  This variable masks the one with the same name at higher scope, which is therefore inaccessible via that name and does not change.

You instead want:

```
ans=answer();
```